# HidSharp Never Receives Input Report

Tags: c#, hid

I'm attempting to use HidSharp to read reports from a Vendor USB HID device using the below code, but I never manage to poll any input.

```
            var device = DeviceList.Local.GetHidDevices().Where(d => /* My Vendor stuff */).First();
            var deviceDescriptor = device.GetReportDescriptor();

            if (device.TryOpen(out var inputStream))
            {
                var inputReport = deviceDescriptor.InputReports.First();
                var inputReportParser = inputReport.DeviceItem.CreateDeviceItemInputParser();
                var inputReportReciever = deviceDescriptor.CreateHidDeviceInputReceiver();
                var inputReportBuffer = new byte[inputReport.Length];

                while (inputReportReciever.IsRunning)
                {
                    if (inputReportReciever.WaitHandle.WaitOne(10000))
                    {
                        while (inputReportReciever.TryRead(inputReportBuffer, 0, out var report))
                        {
                            if (inputReportParser.TryParseReport(inputReportBuffer, 0, report))
                            {
                                if (inputReportParser.HasChanged)
                                {
                                    var data = inputReportParser.GetValue(inputReportParser.GetNextChangedIndex());
                                    Console.WriteLine("Data: " + data.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I can see in the device manager that the device is recognized as an HID USB device, and Wireshark shows that I am sending periodic reports like so:

[image]

(I'm a java developer so I'm really struggling with Visual Studio) I can't step in to the library to see what's happening, but there are no errors being thrown and the 'test' included with the project parses reports from at least one other USB device (a headset) so the library seems ok. I'm not at all sure how to proceed with debugging further. Any direction on this library or USB is appreciated.